# Django-autocomplete-light filtering and displaying results based on two fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-autocomplete-light

I'm a newbie to django-autocomplete-light. I'm trying to implement something like the "global navigation autocomplete" (https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/docs_rewrite/navigation.html#a-simple-view) however this shall be used to navigate between patients.

Here's the problem:

- Let's assume there's a Patient called John Smith.
- If I type "John" **or** "Smith" the right autocomplete appears and I can choose the Patient.
- However - If I type "John S" or any other combination involving typing in both the name and surname the autocomplete becomes empty...
- I tried to filter the model differently, e.g. splitting q into "name" and "surname" and filtering the model with Q on the relevant field but that also doesn't help...

Which part am I missing? Is is the filtering or autocomplete which cannot cope with filtering based on two fields from a given model?

Here's a part of my simple model (please note that the url 'patient_detail' exists and works fine, just not pasting it here):

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=False)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length = 70, blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.name, self.surname)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('patient_detail', kwargs = {'pk':self.pk})
```

Than, I'm doing this (similar to what's described in the docs) in my view, where q get's all I'm typing into the  field:

```
def pacjent_autocomplete(request, template_name = 'reception_autocomplete.html'):
   q = request.GET.get('q','').strip()
   queries = {}
   queries['patients'] = Patient.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=q) | Q(surname__icontains = q))
   return render(request, template_name, queries)
```

The reception_autocomplete.html file looks like this:

```
<span class="separator">Patients</span>
{% for patient in patients %}
<a class="block choice" href="{{patient.get_absolute_url}}">{{patient}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

In my main view I have a  field which is the target of this script:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#id_new_patient').yourlabsAutocomplete({
            url: "{% url 'reception_autocomplete' %}",
            choiceSelector: 'a',
        }).input.bind('selectChoice', function(e, choice, autocomplete) {
            document.location.href = choice.attr('href');
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Your help on how to show the right patient for input like "John Sm" is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a problem with autocomplete_light, but with your Django query:

```
Patient.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=q) | Q(surname__icontains = q))
```

That would select all Patient which have `surname__icontains="John S"` **or** `name__icontains="John S"`. That's why you get no result. Check how django-cities-light does search: https://github.com/yourlabs/django-cities-light/blob/stable/3.x.x/cities_light/abstract_models.py

Or use django-haystack and implement a haystack backend, or redis...

Or, fallback to raw sql in `choices_for_request` to filter against a concatenation of name and surname.

Comment: Thanks a lot for great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If a simple query (using `.filter()` on a single field) or a *complex* one using `Q` (see @jpic's answer) is not fitting your needs, you might also make use of Django's search features (***for Postgres only***), especially `SearchVector`:

It will allow you to combine multiple fields to be searched against.

```
>>> from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
>>> Entry.objects.annotate(
...     search=SearchVector('body_text', 'blog__tagline'),
... ).filter(search='Cheese')
[<Entry: Cheese on Toast recipes>, <Entry: Pizza Recipes>]
```

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/search/#document-based-search and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#django.contrib.postgres.search.SearchVector